CLUSTER BY is not available at Spark version3.5
CLUSTER BY is succesfully executed at Spark version3.4.
But, It failed when I ran the same code at Spark version3.5.
The execution environment is fabrcic spark notbooke.
%%sql
SELECT SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber,'' as CustomerName, SUM(Quantity), SUM(UnitPrice), SUM(TaxAmount)
FROM sales_df
GROUP BY SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber

UNION ALL

SELECT SalesOrderLineNumber,'' as SalesOrderNumber, CustomerName, SUM(Quantity), SUM(UnitPrice), SUM(TaxAmount)
FROM sales_df
GROUP BY SalesOrderLineNumber, CustomerName

UNION ALL

SELECT '' asSalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber, CustomerName, SUM(Quantity), SUM(UnitPrice), SUM(TaxAmount)
FROM sales_df
GROUP BY SalesOrderNumber, CustomerName

CLUSTER BY (SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber)

<error>
[PARSE_SYNTAX_ERROR] Syntax error at or near 'PARTITIONED'.(line 17, pos 0)

== SQL ==
SELECT SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber,'' as CustomerName, SUM(Quantity), SUM(UnitPrice), SUM(TaxAmount)
FROM sales_df
GROUP BY SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber

UNION ALL

SELECT SalesOrderLineNumber,'' as SalesOrderNumber, CustomerName, SUM(Quantity), SUM(UnitPrice), SUM(TaxAmount)
FROM sales_df
GROUP BY SalesOrderLineNumber, CustomerName

UNION ALL

SELECT '' asSalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber, CustomerName, SUM(Quantity), SUM(UnitPrice), SUM(TaxAmount)
FROM sales_df
GROUP BY SalesOrderNumber, CustomerName

PARTITIONED BY (SalesOrderLineNumber, SalesOrderNumber)
^^^

I need to check the cause of the failure to execute.
Does Spark 3.5 support CLUSTER BY function?

is there any specific error message? CLUSTER BY is available at Spark 3.5.0 (considering Databricks Runtime 14.3 LTS) are you using local spark or any other tool like Synapse / Azure Data Factory?

Hello, @LeonardoPedroso
Thank you for your reply.
I have ran CLUSTER BY at fabric spark3.5 notebook.
I need to make sure that spark3.5 supports CLUSTER BY.
I have updated error code.
It is output as a GROUP BY error, not CLUSTER BY.
